# How to compile this Java Server/Client code in CMD

Tags: java, javafx, server, client

I use Windows and I used JGrasp to save this code. The code you see below is perfect and correct (except I added a package name on the top of each class), because it is example code I took off a powerpoint which was made from the course textbook we use. It is a program where a Client has to type a circle radius, the server receives the client's circle radius and then calculates the circle area, sending the cirlce area back to the client. How do I compile AND run this program in command prompt? I never learned about java packages before by the way.

Server

```
package program;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Date;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Server extends Application {
  @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Text area for displaying contents
    TextArea ta = new TextArea();

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(ta), 450, 200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Server"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

    new Thread( () -> {
      try {
        // Create a server socket
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
        Platform.runLater(() ->
          ta.appendText("Server started at " + new Date() + '\n'));

        // Listen for a connection request
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        // Create data input and output streams
        DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(
          socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(
          socket.getOutputStream());

        while (true) {
          // Receive radius from the client
          double radius = inputFromClient.readDouble();

          // Compute area
          double area = radius * radius * Math.PI;

          // Send area back to the client
          outputToClient.writeDouble(area);

          Platform.runLater(() -> {
            ta.appendText("Radius received from client: " 
              + radius + '\n');
            ta.appendText("Area is: " + area + '\n'); 
          });
        }
      }
      catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }).start();
  }

  /**
   * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
   * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Client

```
package program;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Client extends Application {
  // IO streams
  DataOutputStream toServer = null;
  DataInputStream fromServer = null;

  @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Panel p to hold the label and text field
    BorderPane paneForTextField = new BorderPane();
    paneForTextField.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5)); 
    paneForTextField.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green");
    paneForTextField.setLeft(new Label("Enter a radius: "));

    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    paneForTextField.setCenter(tf);

    BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
    // Text area to display contents
    TextArea ta = new TextArea();
    mainPane.setCenter(new ScrollPane(ta));
    mainPane.setTop(paneForTextField);

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 450, 200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Client"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

    tf.setOnAction(e -> {
      try {
        // Get the radius from the text field
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(tf.getText().trim());

        // Send the radius to the server
        toServer.writeDouble(radius);
        toServer.flush();

        // Get area from the server
        double area = fromServer.readDouble();

        // Display to the text area
        ta.appendText("Radius is " + radius + "\n");
        ta.appendText("Area received from the server is "
          + area + '\n');
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
      }
    });

    try {
      // Create a socket to connect to the server
      Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);
      // Socket socket = new Socket("130.254.204.36", 8000);
      // Socket socket = new Socket("drake.Armstrong.edu", 8000);

      // Create an input stream to receive data from the server
      fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

      // Create an output stream to send data to the server
      toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ta.appendText(ex.toString() + '\n');
    }
  }

  /**
   * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
   * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be any different than any piece of code. Packages doesn't change the execution of a program. Just make sure to run the server before the client so it should have where to connect to.

Comment: The above doesn't apply for EE4J (formerly known as JavaEE) which is enterprise server programming, and works completely differently.

Answer (score 0):

you can choose a directory for your root home like D:/. then

1. make a new folder named program (it's your package name)
2. put the Server.java and Client.java into program
3. open the CMD and cd to root path
4. execute: `javac program/Server.java` (maybe `program\Server.java` on windows)
5. execute: `java program.Server`
6. it's run!

Answer (score -1):

1. Compile the Java File to a *.class file : **javac TheJavaFile. java**. This will create a TheJavaFile.class file.
2. Then execute Java file: **java TheJavaFile**

Hope this helps. Also make sure the .java file is in the same folder where javac is located, usually in the JDK

Comment: I have two java files though.

Comment: Yes they will. Your server class needs to be executed on one command screen. This needs to be run first to accept requests. Then open another command prompt to compile and rub the client that will make a connection to the server. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure that Java is already installed in the system with`java -version` command.
2. Create two files named as Server.java and Client.java with content in your question.
3. Compile code using the Java compiler. `javac Client.java Server.java`
4. make a directory named `program`, that is your package name, and move Client.class and Server.class to this directory.
5. run your server code with `java program.Server` and client code with `java program.Client`.

Comment: It says no main class was found for neither of the classes.

Comment: you should execute `java program.Server` and `java program.Client` in the parent directory of `program`. maybe like this. `yourPath/program/`,you should run it in yourPath like  `yourPath/  java program.Server`.